# Converting C++11 code that depends on std::vector initialization list constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, c++11, vector

Since Microsoft won't support a nice C++11 feature of using initialization lists to construct `std::vector` I need to refactor some code for use with the VS compiler, unfortunately.

The best way I can think of is to use the [array pointer and length constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) for `vector`. Previously I had done this:

`MyClass(std::initializer_list<T> init):myStdVector(init){`

This allowed me to do nice things like:

`MyClass hi({1,2,3,4});`

With a variable number of items as I saw fit.

How can I achieve the same elegance by passing an array directly? Is it possible to actually initialize an array within a function parameter?

I could do this:

`MyClass(T*initArray,int arraySize):myStdVector(initArray,initArray+arraySize){`

But then I have to do this:

```
 int whatever[4]={1,2,3,4};
 MyClass hi(whatever,4);
```

Seems clunky. Perhaps I am missing a better solution?

Comment: You'll be happy to know this is all implemented in VS2013.

Comment: @chris great, but not available to me yet

Comment: I think you are not supposed to inherit from std containers as they don't have virtual distructor. Just a hint.

Comment: @RedX I'd guess `myStdVector` is a member, not a base class.

Comment: @RedX there is no inheritance here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a helper function, but you'd have to supply the length, so it's not as nice as the `initializer_list` version.  I've also added another helper (`make_vec2`). If your compiler supports that version, then use that as you don't have to manually specify the array length with that one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass {
    std::vector<int> v;

    MyClass(std::vector<int> values) : v(values) {
    }
};

template <std::size_t N>
std::vector<int>
make_vec(const int (&values)[N]) {
    return std::vector<int>(values, values + N);
}

template <int... vs>
std::vector<int>
make_vec2() {
    int tmp[] = { vs... };
    return std::vector<int>(tmp, tmp + sizeof...(vs));
}

int main() {
    MyClass mc(make_vec<4>({1, 2, 3, 4}));
    MyClass mc2(make_vec2<1, 2, 3, 4>());
    std::cout << mc.v.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << mc2.v.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: you can probably generate the `make_vec<4>({1, 2, 3, 4})` call with a macro like `MAKE_VEC(1, 2, 3, 4)`, but I tend to stay away from macros so that part is left as an exercise. Also, just upgrade your compiler or use another one :)

Comment: VS2010 doesn't support variadic templates. If it did, it would probably support initialiser-list ctors as well.

Comment: Yeah, thought so, but it was still worth mentioning. In that case he'll have to live with specifying the array length :(

Comment: Why can you pass `{1, 2, 3, 4}` as a parameter and it is read in as an actual array if it is supported by the other answers that you cannot similarly pass this to the vector constructor?

Comment: @OpenLearner because you specify the array size explicitly. You can't do that with a ctor, hence the helper function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make your constructor a template, and accept an array by reference. It needs to be a template, because the array length will be a deduced parameter: `template<int N> MyClass::MyClass(int (&array)[N]) { }`. When you pass `int whatever[4]`, N is obviously deduced as 4.

[edit]
Prior to C++11, the snippet `{1,2,3,4}` has no meaning outside the declaration of arrays and POD structs. `MyClass` is neither, which means it's unavoidable to have a declaration of a suitable type, and use that to initialize `MyClass` on the next line.

Comment: How do you initialize `int whatever[4]` within the actual constructor argument without using a second line to first make the array, and then separately pass it to the constructor? This is why the initialization list is so nice.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same, but I cannot see how to do it in one line.

Comment: @OpenLearner: Well, you don't. This just removes the clunky part where  you need to hardcode the array length instead of having the compiler count for you. I.e. `int whatever[] = {1,3,4}; MyClass hi(whatever)` - N is correctly deduced as 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with some [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) hacking:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS /*mind the space here!*/ (1, 10)  //where 10 is the max. number of arguments you can pass

// This macro will be expanded with maN ranging from 1 to 10 (as specified above)
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(maN) \
  template <class T> \
  std::array<T, maN> make_array(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(maN, T arg)) { \
    std::array<T, maN> arr; \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(maN, ASSIGN_ONE, %%) \
    return arr; \
  }

// BOOST_PP_REPEAT will expand this with maIdx randing from 0 to its first argument - 1 (maN-1 in your case)
#define ASSIGN_ONE(maZ, maIdx, maData) \-
  arr[maIdx] = BOOST_PP_CAT(arg, maIdx);


// Performs the actual expansion
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()


// Usage:
template <size_t N>
MyClass(std::array<T, N> arr) : myStdVector(begin(arr), end(arr)) {}

int main() {
  MyClass(make_array(1, 2, 3));
}
```

Of course, you can tailor it further (such as creating such "variadic" overloads for the constructor directly etc.).